# Am I using 'this' correctly? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a click event - where it hides any `users` that are not the same value as the one clicked on. This is a snippet of the relevant HTML.

```
<div class="main">
        <section class="tweets">
        <div class="tweet">
           <p class="time">Sun Mar 15 2020 20:04:53 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)</p>
           <p class="users" data="sharksforcheap">@sharksforcheap: </p>
           <p class="message">last night i formulated a life #sxsw</p></div>
```

When I manually input the value of the `users` value in my `:contains` it works fine. I'll click on `sharksforcheap` for example and it will hide every other `users` that are not of that.

```
    $('.tweets').on('click', '.users', function(){

      var user = $(this).data('users');
      $('.tweet').not(':contains(sharksforcheap)').hide(); 
    });
```

However, I want to obviously make it work for any `users` that I click on as hard-coding it for each user is not feasible. So I made a var called user and referenced it to `this` which should hold the data of my `users`. However, this doesn't work.

```
     $('.tweets').on('click', '.users', function(){

      var user = $(this).data('users');
      $('.tweet').not(':contains('+ user + ')').hide(); 
    });
```

Am I using `this` incorrectly in this context?

Comment: You need to define something like this `<p class="users" data-users="sharksforcheap">@sharksforcheap: </p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you need to specify `data-users` attribute to get its value with `.data("users")`:

```
<p class="users" data-users="sharksforcheap">@sharksforcheap: </p>
```

But it seems that what you need is easier achieved with

```
$('.tweet').not($(this).closest('.tweet')).hide();
```

Comment: Thank you Igor. I appreciate your help here and in my other thread. If I'm understanding correctly, is the keyword `data` linked? As in when I am adding in `data-users` does it need to include `data` in there? or could I just simply have put it at `users="sharksforcheap"`.

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis It has to be as I showed - `data-users="sharksforcheap"`.

Comment: I guess I'm puzzled. So `data-` has to be linked to whatever I called to hold my element value?

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis I don't understand the term "linked". `data-...` is part of HTML specification, jQuery let's us get such attribute values using `.data('...')` function.

Comment: I think that answers it for me. By linked I meant that when you called `.data('...')` it will look for whatever was called inside the parenthesis but that HTML code would need to have `data-` included with it. I thought `.data` was a function but it seems to me it needs an identifier of `data-`